# CSV to Geotiff using GDAL in C#

Tags: c#, csv, gdal, geotiff

First post here, apologies for any improper etiquette. I am very new to GDAL.

As the title suggests I am trying to take data in the form of a csv file and create a geotiff of this data. The csv file has a structure as follows with over 40k lines:

```
id,Longitude,Latitude,Z_GPS,CA
1,-99.5228,49.9973,1278.8067,1917.5495
```

I am currently working with a console application for testing but it will eventually be part of a web application. I've scoured the net for information and it seems like it is easier to do in python but I have been tasked to write it in c#. There also seems to be little documentation on how to use GDAL in C#. I am using the GDAL.NET installed through nuget using windows 10. Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using CsvHelper;
using OSGeo.GDAL;
using Ogr = OSGeo.OGR.Ogr;

namespace CSV_To_GeoTiff
{
  public class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Configures gdal and sets up the drivers
        GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();

        //Declare an empty dataset
        OSGeo.GDAL.Dataset ds;

        //Path and string setup
        string path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"..\..\.."));
        string csvFile = "Ca.csv";
        string vrtFile = "Ca.vrt";
        string tifFile = "Ca.tif";
        string lyr_name = "";
        //DirectoryInfo oDir = Directory.CreateDirectory(path + @"\Output");

        Console.WriteLine(path);
        Console.ReadLine();

        //Read the csv file and grab the name of the last column to be used as the layer name of the geotiff
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path + "\\" + csvFile))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            csv.Read();
            csv.ReadHeader();
            string[] headerRow = csv.Context.HeaderRecord;
            lyr_name = headerRow[headerRow.Length - 1];
        }

        //Set up the vrt file with appropriate tags from the csv data
        string[] vrtTags = { "<OGRVRTDataSource>",
                        "\t" + $"<OGRVRTLayer name=\"{lyr_name}\">",
                        "\t\t" + $"<SrcDataSource>{csvFile}</SrcDataSource>",
                        "\t\t" +"<GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>",
                        "\t\t" + "<LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>",
                        "\t\t" + $"<GeometryField encoding=\"PointFromColumns\" x=\"Longitude\" y=\"Latitude\" z=\"{lyr_name}\"/>",
                        "\t" + "</OGRVRTLayer>",
                        "</OGRVRTDataSource>"
                    };

        string vrtPath = path + @"\Output\" + vrtFile;
        string csvPath = path + "\\" +csvFile;

        //Create and write the tags into the VRT file in an output directory for testing
        File.WriteAllLines(vrtPath, vrtTags);            

        ds = Gdal.OpenEx(vrtPath, 0, null, null, null);

        //Creates the raster file in the output folder
        Gdal.wrapper_GDALGrid(path + @"\Output\"+ tifFile, ds, null, null, string.Empty);

    }
  }
}
```

I am getting an error on the line Gdal.wrapper_GDALGrid that states "System.ApplicationException: 'Failed to open datasource `Ca.csv'.'". Which to me, means the vrt file is being read properly and it is trying to open the csv file, but something is going wrong. I don't know what I am doing wrong or how to fix it. I placed the csv file in the same location as the vrt file (in the Output directory) as I assume it needs to be in the same location.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated and thanks for your time.